# Unable to install iOS Simulators 5.0 and 4.3 in xcode 4.3.2/preferences/downloads/components

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Hi All I have recently installed Xcode 4.3.2.I want to install the iOS simulator 5.0 and 4.3 from Xcode/preferences/downloads/components.But when i click install button on this above path it shows abc@gmail.com(which is my developer apple login id) does not access to iOSSimulator.I am not sure of this issue how to solve.Presently I have the access to 5.1simulator. Without installing the 5.0 and 4.3 simulators i can't access to others simulators and device debuggingsupport.So please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you log into the Developer site and accept any new Terms and Conditions. I got locked out because of that. What happens is your developer account contracts arent valid and so you can't access resources. Kind of annoying, but part of the process. Usually this only happens after major updates or before them.

Here's the link if you need it: [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action)

Also, it could be I scheduled downtime. Just a warning!